# Do I have to make a custom implementation of RowSorter when custom insert behavior is needed?

Tags: java, swing, tablerowsorter

I need a JTable with insert behavior that is different the one TableRowSorter/DefaultRowSorter provide.

I need a table such that when user inserts a row, the newly inserted row should go below the one where the cursor was, and cursor placed at the newly inserted row.
Let me illustrate it on an example:

Initial state - table has 4 rows:

```
0. Row 1
1. Row 2 <-- cursor here
2. Row 3
3. Row 4
```

User's cursor is at the second row, and user triggers insertion. The newly inserted row appears below, and cursor moves there as well:

```
0. Row 1
1. Row 2 
2. New row <-- cursor here
3. Row 3
4. Row 4
```

I understand pretty well that I have two approaches to solve this problem.

First approach is to change my model, so insertion is done at right place in the model. I do not like this solution as it means model indexes will change in all rows below the inserted one. This is the easiest way to accomplish what I need, but, as i said, at the cost of potentially big overhead caused by model indexes change...

Second approach is to implement a RowSorter that will maintain own videToModel[] and modelToView[] arrays and maintain right order when rows are inserted. Naturally, I started by extending TableRowSorter but problem is that modelToView and viewToModel are private arrays and I can't access them so I have problems when rows are filtered...

I am trying to avoid writing my own RowSorter implementation because it will take time to do it right...

**UPDATE 2013-10-07:**
I have accomplished this by implementing my own RowSorter. After experimenting with both approaches I realised the second one gives me more flexibility.

Comment: Are you aware of concrete performance hits of inserting data in the middle of a model?  If not, I'm leaning towards your first option - calling `DefaultTableModel.insertRow()` with the correct model index (converted from the selected row's view index).

Answer (score 1):

The "right" way to get a JTable that uses a RowSorter to sort correctly is to override `AbstractTableModel.getColumnClass(int)`.  Then you can call `DefaultRowSorter.setSortKeys()` to specify the sort order.

These methods will allow you to add/delete rows to/from your model in any order and be satisfied they will be displayed in the "correct" sorted order.

If you need special sorting, i.e. sorting based on something other than the objects' `compareTo()` methods, you can call `DefaultRowSorter.setComparator()` to provide your own comparison function to work on that column.

I'm not sure what you mean by "cursor", but if you mean that any newly-inserted row should be selected, that would be accomplished by calling `JTable.setRowSelectionInterval()`, which takes *view indices*, so they need to be converted (e.g. convert your model index, possibly the last row in the model that you just inserted, into a view index).

Comment: Rob, I wish it is that simple! :) I fail to see how can Comparator help here... I may not have SortKeys at all, but still want insert to happen at the row where cursor is! :) I know how to select newly inserted row but thanks saying that anyway. +1 for trying to help! :)

Comment: Ah!  I see now - sorry I need things explained twice usually.  Since your sorting is completely based on data that is not in the table, my first instinct is to add an extra hidden column to hold the "sort order".  Not sure that would be easy - let me think about it and edit my answer if it comes to me.

Comment: So it turns out I like your first solution.  I posted a second answer since this one seems totally off...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I should have just edited my original answer but I think it's completely wrong now.

I think your first solution is the best.  I wouldn't be worried about inserting data in the table model being costly until I saw it first-hand (or if you knew you had hundreds of thousands of rows or something).

So - something like this is what I'd go for:

```
int modelIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());
tableModel.insertRow(modelIndex, myRowVector);
```

Glancing at the `DefaultTableModel` code, it looks like this might be a fairly fast method, though there's probably no way around the `Vector.insertElementAt()` overhead... I would be willing to bet it's a lower overhead altogether than using a `RowSorter` at all.

Comment: It is actually complicated with the TableModel approach... Table may be sorted/filtered, and I still want to insert at the row where the cursor is... (The currently selected cell)

Comment: So the table may be "sorted" by something separate from this row insertion?  That sounds like it could be confusing - does the inserted row always get data that matches the sort order?

Comment: Sorting stops when you insert row. That only makes sense... If it does not, suer may not see inserted row, and that can lead at multiple insertions, and trouble. That is the main reason why I want user to see the newly inserted row right below the cursor - you get immediate feedback that row is inserted...

Comment: OK, good!  So - does it work to uninstall the `RowSorter` when inserting a row?  Or somehow stop it from sorting.  Otherwise it would attempt to re-sort the inserted row.  Hmm.  Now I'm not sure what that would do to the filtering.  It's almost like you want to freeze the current order, use that as the "sorted order", and insert the row in a way that gets it sorted to the right place.  Sounds like it could be a pain, especially if you have tons of rows...